# ngTagsInput Autocomplete on focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the ngTagsInput directive which is documented here: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api

The directive has functionality to show an auto-complete list when the user starts to type into the input. I'd like to adjust the directive so that as soon as the user enters into the input, a list of tags is displayed and then filters as the user types.

The filtering as the user types functionality already exists. But, how can I get it so that a list of tags is displayed immediately when a user clicks into the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive has built in attributes to handle this functionality.

```
                 load-on-focus="true"
                 load-on-empty="true"
```

both of those attributes need to be added to the `<auto-complete>` element and now when the user focuses on the tag input a list of tags appears.